# collectionview configuration with headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have 2 objects, lets call them super and sub, each super object is a standalone object, but each sub object must contain a property of that super object.
Now i'm trying to configure a collection view

lets say I have 4 super objects and 70 sub objects, I want a section for each super object,
and I want to display all 70 sub objects (since each sub object has its super property) I wanna organize those sub objects under their relevant super object

for now I have all sub objects into an array of something like 70 objects in count.
but how do I organize everything and make it dynamic ? so that if i'll add more sub objects they will go straight under their correct super object section

basically need help configuring these:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of array.

```
NSArray *subObjectArrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:subObjectArray1, subOjectArray2, subObjectArray3, subObjectArray4, nil];
```

where `subObjectArray1`, `subObjectArray2`, `subObjectArray3`, `subObjectArray4` are different arrays for every super object.

In `numberOfItemsInSection` method:

```
 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return  [[subObjectArrays objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should have an array of arrays, one subarray for each of the super objects. If you need to have more information for each super object, you could have an array of dictionaries, and each of the dictionaries contain an array for all the subobjects.

Then, to configure the collection view, you would do it just like this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [superObjects count];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [superObjects objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

If you needed to add more super or sub objects, you can add them to the data structures and call `reloadData` on the collection view.